# ThreeJS Tread Rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

In ThreeJS, I am trying to make a tread with a certain material rotate, similar to a tank tread. Here's an example of what I'm thinking of: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X87J.jpg

I'm thinking that, opposed to actually rotating the tread along its two points, it would generate the same effect visually if I were to simply change the position of the texture of the tread, offsetting it by a certain amount of pixels continuously. Does anybody know how one would go about shifting the position of a repeating texture in ThreeJS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the wrap mode like so:

```
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; // or wrapT, as appropriate
```

Then, in the render loop use a pattern like so:

```
mesh.material.map.offset.x += 0.01;
```

three.js r.66